# How to use Facebook login in windows phone application

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm developing a Windows Phone application, which has its own login as well as the [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) login.

For Facebook login, If the user already has the Facebook account integrated in the Facebook application then this app has to access the Facebook login info such as `username`, `email` from Facebook and register with the cloud service using that retrieved info.

Please let me know how to access the integrated Facebook account information in Windows Phone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to get user details (specifically email id)??

Comment: i'm also stuck in getting the email id?